# Issue in printing a session array variable

Tags: smarty

I have an peculiar session array variable,I need to pick one element to display on the screen.I'm not sure how to do that in smarty.Please give me the syntax how to manipulate the element in smarty.Here is the array values. I need to select ["school_name"] from the set.Please help

```
   array(6) {
     ["id"]=> string(32) "cb60942f64d2b7bae2076926ae430f1d"
     ["sa"]=> NULL ["start_cache_timer"]=> int(1377752940)  ["user"]=>
   array(17) {
      ["host_id"]=> string(1) "9"
      ["user_id"]=> string(2) "16"
      ["school_name"]=> string(10) "Joseph High School"
      ["code"]=> string(10) "2E4C5339F8"
      ["academic_id"]=>  string(2) "21"
      ["title"]=>  string(2) "Mr"
      ["first_name"]=>  string(3) "Jon"
      ["last_name"]=> string(7) "Bachura"
      ["name"]=> string(11) "Jon Bachura"
      ["email"]=> string(12) "jon@yeks.org"
      ["role"]=> string(1) "1"
      ["times_login"]=> int(656)
      ["acc_status"]=> string(1) "3"
      ["user_status"]=> string(1) "3"
      ["admin_user_id"]=>
      string(2) "16"
      ["life"]=>
     array(2) {
     ["current"]=>
      int(1377756843)
      ["start"]=>
        int(1377756843)
       }
      ["training"]=>
      array(1) {
      ["start_time"]=>
     float(1377752946.14)
   }
   }
    ["mrole"]=>
     NULL
      ["extAjaxSession"]=>
    int(3)
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $smarty.session:

```
$smarty.session.user.school_name
```

Comment: Periklis. Thanks for reminding. I had accepted your answer it was helpful.